# Am I exposed to WebRTC leaks if my IP resulting from WebRTC is the IP of my VPN server with the last digit augmented by one?

Tags: vpn, data-leakage, webrtc

I am connecting to the [website](https://www.expressvpn.com/webrtc-leak-test) of ExpressVPN that checks for WebRTC IP leaks.

My IP as resulting from that website is the same IP of the VPN server I am connected to but with the last digit augmented by 1.

That is, if IP address of my VPN server is

A.B.C.D (e.g. 1.2.3.4)

the IP as detected from that website is

A.B.C.(D+1) (e.g. 1.2.3.5)

What does this result mean?

Why is the last digit augmented by one?

Am I exposed to WebRTC leaks?

EDIT: More information:
Actually `A.B.C.D` is the IP address I have on my openvpn configuration files.
That is, inside the openvpn configuration file there is written
`remote A.B.C.D 443`
But when I connect to say https://whatismyipaddress.com/ I see A.B.C.(D+1)

Comment: What IP addresses [this site](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/) shows? Click on **Gather Candidates**.

Comment: It shows 6 candidates. 2 of which are `65b34986-87ce-40c5-98f4-f6198f5c2c66.local` over tcp, 2 of which have the same address over udp, the other 2 are the A.B.C.(D+1) pattern above

Comment: Edited to add more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your own IP address is not visible, your private IP addresses are not leaking.

The reason you might see a different IP address in the network of your VPN provider is because of the way your VPN provider's network is set up.

You might want to disable WebRTC in your browser to be on the safe side.

Comment: I accepted your answer and edited my question to add more information

Comment: In order to avoid leaking any information, even if it is only your assigned IP address in the VPn network, you can consider disabling WebRTC. In Firefox you can install uBlock Origin and check the option to Disable WebRTC. If you care about privacy you should definitely not use Google Chrome or some browser vendor who makes a living of collecting user data to make a business (selling ads or the information itself).

Comment: just for confirmation, if I disable WebRTC altogether I will not be able to use Zoom, right? By the results I don't seem to be exposed for some reason, if I understand correctly, and uBlock Origin seems to have an option to avoid IP leakage through WebRTC without blocking WebRTC altogether ... isn't it good enough?

Comment: I have had WebRTC disabled for a long time and I can still attend Zoom meetings and use other meeting/video conferencing services. Leaking IP addresses of your VPN service is ok and nothing to worry about unless the IP address you are leaking are unique to your VPN account so it can be used to differentiate you from other users of the same VPN provider. If it is one number higher than your VPN IP address I don't think that would be the case though.